# Set anchorpoint for rotation in Titanium

Tags: rotation, titanium, anchor

How can I set an anchor-point for the rotation of an image.

Over here, I need to place other images in a rotated/tilted manner w.r.t to the first image. So I need to set an anchor-point of rotation for the first image

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show some code? Have you checked [this out on the docs?](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-anchorPoint)

Answer (score 3):

On android you have to set the anchor point on the transform matrix.
On iOS you have to set the anchor point to the view you are trying to rotate.

> **IMPORTANT UNDOCUMENTED BEHAVIOUR:**
>   I've been struggling with this for a week and found out the following: If you try to set the anchorpoint to a view without first setting it's width or height, or setting them to Ti.UI.SIZE the anchorpoint will always be at 0,0.

You can try this code snippet which should work. Haven tested it, but you can get the idea.
This code should work for both platforms.

```
var anchor_x = 0.5;
var anchor_y = 0.5;

var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    // ALWAYS SET THE HEIGHT AND WIDTH!!!!
    // IF NOT ANCHOR WILL BE CALCULATED FROM WIDTH = 0 AND HEIGHT = 0
    width: Ti.UI.FILL
    height: Ti.UI.FILL
});

// It it's ios (iPad or iPhone)
if (Ti.Platform.platform == 'iPhone OS')
    view.anchorPoint = {x: anchor_x, y: anchor_y};

var transform;
// If it's android, create the 2DMatrix with the desired anchorpoint.
if (Ti.Platform.platform == 'android')
    transform = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix({anchorPoint: { x: anchor_x, y: anchor_y }});
else
    transform = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();

// Apply rotation
transform = transform.rotate(90);

// Apply transformation to your view.
view.transform = transform;
```